# alert element clicked from website in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

For a requirement, I have a iframe in my html page like this

```
<iframe src="www.abc.com" id="firstembed" name="iframebox"></iframe>
```

So, the given URL (www.abc.com) will get loaded in the iframe.  Now, my requirement is, if user click on the area of iframe(for ex: image or dropdown etc), I need to display the alert message containing name, id or text etc.

Please advice me how we can detect the click event on iframe element using JQuery.

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that the question fits SO standards

Comment: Typically you can't as that would violate cross site scripting policies. Do you control abc.com in this example? If so you could load a script in abc.com that talks to the outer frame.

Comment: thanks for reply ,,,,,is their any concept or idea or any other languages which can be used to load other domain website . My primary aim is to fetch the element name(div id, text, value etc )by clicking on the element, on the other domain for ex: like amazon